# Android LinearLayout divider, but percentage?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, xml-layout

In happy.xml I have a LinearLayout...

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:divider="@drawable/happy_spacer"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    ...>
```

Here's the file happy_spacer.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:height="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="#90909090" />
</shape>
```

Fantastic, the spacer is 8dp high.

But you can't work like that anymore in a responsive world, the height of the spacer has to be a certain percentage of the height of the page it is sitting in.

(Or, it has to - say - relate to the height of something else on happy.xml.)

What's the Android solution?

*(**Important** - as Charuka explains below, you almost certainly want "px" physical pixels in such a situation, not dp or dip.)*

For modern Android, apk 21 forward only.

Comment: It exist a support library to handle percent but it's only PercentRelativeLayout and PercentFrameLayout... I don't think it's possible to use a percent for a shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, at least in my experience, list item dividers *are* a static height. In any case, I do not think you can make it a percentage of the screen height using XML, but you can programmatically using [`setDividerHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setDividerHeight(int)); though you will have to calculate the size based on the percentage yourself.

Otherwise, you can adjust the size based on specific [break points](https://material.google.com/layout/responsive-ui.html#responsive-ui-breakpoints) by using [resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources); such as `h720dp` (minimum height of 720dp) or `w600dp` (minimum width of 600dp).

Comment: Wait, `setDividerHeight` does *not* apply to LinearLayout, correct?

Comment: @JoeBlow No, but if you really wanted to, you should be able to create a `Drawable` at the size you would like, and then use [`setDividerDrawable()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setDividerDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

Comment: Say, @Bryan I was wondering in Android terminology, what's the difference between "resource qualifiers" and "configuration qualifiers" (if any)?  Cheers

Comment: @JoeBlow Same thing, I think the more accepted term may be "configuration qualifiers". They qualify specific resources based on device configuration, haha

Comment: @JoeBlow Wow, thank you. Completely unnecessary, but I'm glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [configuration qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) and provide different dimens:

e.g.

```
// happy_spacer.xml
<size android:height="@dimen/divider" />

// values/dimens.xml
<dimen name="divider">8dp</dimen>

// values-w720dp/dimens.xml
<dimen name="divider">16dp</dimen>

// values-w820dp/dimens.xml
<dimen name="divider">24dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 1):

agrees with [Bryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41125343/5188159) and if you use your `divider` inside a list item you can use `setDividerHeight()` method. But if you directly use your divider inside a `LinearLayout` you only have `linearLayout.setDividerDrawable();`

**Note :**

You should use 8px instead of 8dp or 8dip,if you use dp or dip Android will scale that down depending the device dpi.So it changes a bit depending the device in a responsive world ;) which looks bit ugly. So to *have your real question* you should use height in `px` value which is clear and same size for any screen... .

Comment: Thanks.  (You're right, to some extent, just using dp/dip provides some reactivity!)